# AND and OR query in WordPress wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Right, I have [read through the entire *wpdb*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and [ezSQL](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql) so I have a very  good understanding of what the wpdb class can do...essentially wpdb is to SQL what jQuery is to Javascript!

As I have never done this before, I am not going to feel too bad about not trying my hand at SQL but this is what I did today to show I have tried, only to later read that AND and OR cannot be used in WP_Query :\

The final outcome should be that if a *user selects from the ProductType dropdown* and clicks the search button, the page should return the results based on that term from the select menu. If they *select an option from ProductGroup* and hit the search button then the results need to return based on the selection.

If *both dropdown menus have options selected, both ProductType and ProductGroup needs to be queried* and the results returned.

```
    $args = array(

        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'relation'=>'AND', // or OR
        'relation'=>'OR',  // this is naturally not correct
        'meta_query' => array(
               array(
                   'key'        =>  'product_type',
                   'value'      =>  $ProductType,
                   'compare'    =>  'LIKE'
               ),
               array(
                    'key'       =>  'product_group',
                    'value'     =>  $ProductGroup,
                    'compare'   =>  'LIKE'
                )
            )

    );

        <form name="x" action="" method="GET" class="search-results-form" >
          <select name="productType" class="search-product-type">
                <option value="">Product Type</option>
                <option value="ProductType1">ProductType1</option>
                <option value="ProductType2">ProductType2</option>
          </select>
          <select name="productGroup" class="search-product-type">
                <option value="">Product Type</option>
                <option value="ProductGroup1">ProductGroup1</option>
                <option value="ProductGroup2">ProductGroup2</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="submit-button btn" />
        </form>
```

I hope this makes sense, so if someone can give me a starting point, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relation condition like this :--

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'=>'AND', // or OR
        array(
            'key'        =>  'product_type',
            'value'      =>  $ProductType,
            'compare'    =>  'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       =>  'product_group',
            'value'     =>  $ProductGroup,
            'compare'   =>  'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

And you also can change `relation` based on your need...

Comment: Thanks Akshay...I see I should have titled my page differently. I need to use both AND and OR which apparently is not allowed hence the move to write an SQL query using wpdb

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but in case anyone stumbles on (like I did), this should work:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        // 'relation'=>'AND', // Not required, as it defaults to "AND"
        'meta_query' => array()
    );

    if (isset($_GET['product_type']) && !empty($_GET['product_type'])) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'        =>  'product_type',
            'value'      =>  $ProductType,
            'compare'    =>  'LIKE'
        );
    }
    if (isset($_GET['product_group']) && !empty($_GET['product_group'])) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'        =>  'product_group',
            'value'      =>  $productGroup,
            'compare'    =>  'LIKE'
        );
    }
?>

<form name="x" action="" method="GET" class="search-results-form" >
    <select name="productType" class="search-product-type">
        <option value="">Product Type</option>
        <option value="ProductType1">ProductType1</option>
        <option value="ProductType2">ProductType2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="productGroup" class="search-product-type">
        <option value="">Product Type</option>
        <option value="ProductGroup1">ProductGroup1</option>
        <option value="ProductGroup2">ProductGroup2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="submit-button btn" />
</form>
```